# WSO2 Identity Server - SSO for ASP.NET - Unable to get the sample working

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 products and I am also trying to get my head around all the security concepts that are explained in their documentation.

I followed all the steps on [the SSO ASP.NET tutorial](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2015/05/tutorial-single-sign-on-for-asp.net-mvc4-web-applications-with-wso2-identity-server/) but cannot get it to work. I am stuck at the point where it shows the SSO challenge page - what UserID/pwd should I enter? The tutorial starts with a clean install of WSO2-IS 5.0.0, using the Resident Identity Provider but doesn't talk anything about setting up the user accounts anywhere. I tried creating a new user in the Resident Identity store, but it doesn't work. Not sure if there's any additional role/permission set up that needs to be done.

If someone was able to get this example working, can you please let me know what I am missing?